# Дублирование контрагентов в результате запроса

Tags: 1с, запрос

Добрый день!
1С:Предприятие 8.2 (8.2.13.219) нетиповая конфигурация

Прошу помочь правильно составить запрос для отчета.
Запрос

```
ВЫБРАТЬ РАЗЛИЧНЫЕ
    СпрКонтрагенты.Ссылка КАК Контрагенты,
    ВЫБОР
        КОГДА ПОДСТРОКА(СпрПользователи.Наименование, 1, 2) = "РО"
            ТОГДА ""
        КОГДА ПОДСТРОКА(СпрПользователи.Наименование, 1, 5) = "АРХИВ"
            ТОГДА ""
        КОГДА ПОДСТРОКА(СпрПользователи.Наименование, 1, 8) = "Приемный"
            ТОГДА ""
        ИНАЧЕ СпрПользователи.Наименование
    КОНЕЦ КАК Закреплено,
    ВЫБОР
        КОГДА РегНакРазмещениеРекламы.ИзданиеПроект.НашеИздание = Истина
            ТОГДА "да"
    КОНЕЦ КАК РазмещаетсяУНас

ИЗ
    Справочник.Контрагенты КАК СпрКонтрагенты
        ЛЕВОЕ СОЕДИНЕНИЕ Справочник.Пользователи КАК СпрПользователи
        ПО СпрКонтрагенты.ОсновнойМенеджерПокупателя = СпрПользователи.Ссылка
        ЛЕВОЕ СОЕДИНЕНИЕ РегистрНакопления.РазмещениеРекламы КАК РегНакРазмещениеРекламы
        ПО РегНакРазмещениеРекламы.Клиент = СпрКонтрагенты.Ссылка
```

Получаем такой результат [image]

и видим, что контрагенты продублированы. А мне это совсем не нужно.
Дело в том, что `РегистрНакопления.РазмещениеРекламы` содержит информацию о всех размещениях контрагента - о тех, что были у нас и не у нас, и, видимо, поэтому в результате контры дублируются.

Comment: Очевидно проблема в регистре. Почему он накопления? Какие размещения вас интересуют? - "Последние" или вообще были ли размещения "у вас".
Видится правильным использование регистра сведений, взять у него СрезПоследних и связывать с ним, будет одна запись...

Comment: Если взять таблицу регистра накопления СрезПоследних, тогда связываться будет одна запись - крайняя в указанном периоде, но в условии задачи сказано "если размещается у нас, была только одна строка, даже, если есть записи о других размещениях"

Comment: СрезПоследних тоже можно фильтровать. По измерению размещение, условие равно "нам", получим как раз либо пусто если никогда у нас не размещалось и "да", если было хотя бы раз у нас. Условия задачи неточные, начальные данные тоже, поэтому были наводящие вопросы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тот вопрос, который я задал - олицетворяет те примеры отчетов, которые начальство хотело видеть. Я поковырялся, и решил, что не надо все пихать в кучу - это и сделать будет тяжелее, и разбираться в этих результатах будет нисколько не легче.
После нескольких дней масштабной декомпозиции, сделал несколько разных отчетов. В принципе я их продолжаю делать. Как оказалось, это намного проще, чем использование половины базы в одном отчете :)) Хотя и тут приходится мудрить с запросами...
Получилась вот такая красота ;)

[image]

[image]

PS. спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 2):

Из запроса вижу, результат будет такой как вы привели на скрине.
для полноты картины нужно немного изменить запрос.
В частности

"

```
ВЫБОР
     КОГДА РегНакРазмещениеРекламы.ИзданиеПроект.НашеИздание = Истина
            ТОГДА "да"
    КОНЕЦ КАК РазмещаетсяУНас"
```

нужно дополнить отражением значения нет.

---

```
ВЫБОР
        КОГДА РегНакРазмещениеРекламы.ИзданиеПроект.НашеИздание = Истина
            ТОГДА "Да"
        Иначе "Нет"
    КОНЕЦ КАК РазмещаетсяУНас
```

Ну и добавте условие

```
Где 
   ВЫБОР
        КОГДА РегНакРазмещениеРекламы.ИзданиеПроект.НашеИздание = Истина
            ТОГДА "Да"
        Иначе "Нет"
    КОНЕЦ = &РазмещениеУНас
```

Если один и тот же контрагент размещается и у вас и в другом издании, то  без условия фильтрации выборки вы получите все записи выборки. 
[image: это разные записи!]
Это разные записи. Пустое значение колонки Размещается у нас - это не представленное значение "Ложь" ("Нет");
Для сравнения братите внимание на Макмарт.

Comment: Если в регистре будет несколько записей с "нашим" размещением (за разные периоды), то в выборке также будет несколько строк.

Comment: в таком случае используем группировки. Но при этом в выборке не должно быть периода.

Comment: 1. Если я использую вышеописанное условие, то в результате запроса не получаю ничего.  
2. Можно ли выбирать из регистра по каждому контрагенту последнее значение размещения? Если да, то получится, что в результате мы получим всех контрагентов из справочника, и к каждому из них будет подставлено одно (последнее) значение размещения.

Comment: 2. Тогда правильным замечанием является утверждение выше - "Видится правильным использование регистра сведений, взять у него СрезПоследних и связывать с ним, будет одна запись". К тому же это более верное решение, чем использовать Регистр Накопления. Все-таки размещение - это сведения!

Comment: Если бы я мог, я бы использовал регистр сведений. Но я не меняю конфигурацию, я лишь работаю с ней. Поэтому приходится выкручиваться...

Comment: Покажите структуру регистра. Не вижу криминала в том, чтобы добавить нужный регистр сведений, даже если он будет участвовать только в одном отчете. Тем более конфигурация нетиповая...

Answer (score 1):

Навскидку могу сказать что надо выгрузить результаты запроса в таблицу и перед выводе на экран обработать строки полученной таблицы.

Comment: Можно и так, но зачем? Всю обработку ТЗ можно выполнить сразу в запросе.